# How to test update of Android application?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I need to test application update because it has major changes in database structure

i tried to use adb install -r app.apk, but it says INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

here everyone says that you need to uninstall app from device, but i need to UPDATE. I think this situation may occur when i trying to update from app from market with release signatures to development apk build from android studio

P.S. sorry for my english if in my post some mistakes, i'm from Russia

Comment: You can update your application if you are using the same keystore you used for creating apk in market. Is it?

Answer (score 2):

The signing key of the already installed app version and of the new version must be the same. Either try the update from a version signed with the debug key or prepare your new version signed with the production key.